# Understanding the RMS noise for a given bandwidth

Tags: stability, instrumentation, current, noise

I would like to ask a technical question regarding the current source Keithley Series 2400 Model 2450. I am looking for a high stability current source capable of feeding some Hall probes with a nominal current of 10 mA. According to the 2450's datasheet, for a current range of 100 mA, the RMS noise is 100 nA for the bandwidth below 10 Hz, as you can see below.

[image]

Could someone please help me to figure out in detail what this specification means? For example, if I set the 2450 with a current of 10 mA (100 mA range) and measure the current samples with a sampling rate of 10 Hz, should I expect a RMS value of 100 nA around the nominal 10 mA? Is that correct?

What if I measure the 2450's output with a sampling rate of 50 Hz? Can we estimate the RMS value as 100 nA * (50/10)^.5 = 223 nA? Would this be correct?

Thank you.